# Electron: Desktop Capturer is coming as undefined

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to build an app where I need to take screenshots. But when I import `desktopCapturer`, it is `undefined`.

Here is how I am importing,

`import { desktopCapturer } from 'electron'`

Comment: In which process are you importing it - main or renderer?

Comment: I was doing it in main process, just found that it is available in rendrer process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`desktopCapturer` is supposed to be used in the Renderer process. If you look at the [docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/desktop-capturer.md), it will say:

> Process: Renderer

You're importing it in the main process. Instead, import it in the renderer process.

Comment: I'm new to electron - what is the Renderer process?

Comment: @developer82 If you're using the electron quick start app, it's what runs index.js or renderer.js. Basically the page you load into your BrowserWindow and all of its required scripts are running in the renderer process.

Comment: Not starting from Electron 17 =) During to security improvement it was moved to main process only https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/30720